# Input increase decrease effects other inputs in cart array php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, button, input, submit

I have this input what was working, I added minus and plus button, they work when the first item is in the array but in the second added item the buttons disturb other inputs. Maybe the id is same can't figure out, can anyone correct it pls?

Before:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" 
         maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        <input name="size" type="hidden" value="' . $size . '" />
        <input name="key_of_session" type="hidden" value="' . $key_of_session . '">
    </form>
```

After adding buttons and javascript:
[image: Färst row workäng second dästurbed]

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
       <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <button type="submit" type="button" class="btn-add btn btn-primary" 
         onclick="plusbot(), submit() ">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
       </div>
        <input id = "kilohere" class="form-control counter" onchange="this.form.submit()"   
         data-min="1" max="99" name="quantity" type="text" 
         value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
       <div class="input-group-append">
        <button  type="submit" value = "-" onclick="minusbot(), submit()"  
         class="btn-subtract btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
       </div>
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $item_id . '" />
        <input name="size" type="hidden" value="' . $size . '" />
        <input name="key_of_session" type="hidden" value="' . $key_of_session . '">
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function minusbot()
    {
        document.getElementById('kilohere').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('kilohere').value) - 1;
        var checknumifzero = parseInt(document.getElementById('kilohere').value);

        if(checknumifzero < 1) //preventing to get negative value
        {
            document.getElementById('kilohere').value = 1;
        }
    }   

    function plusbot()
    {
        document.getElementById('kilohere').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('kilohere').value) + 1;
        var checknumiffifty = parseInt(document.getElementById('kilohere').value);

        if(checknumiffifty > 50) //just a limit
        {
            document.getElementById('kilohere').value = 50;
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

This button should be shown when quantity = 1 instead of the minus button

```
<button type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" 
                id="button">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>
        <input name="index_to_remove" 
               type="hidden" 
               value="' . $i . '" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your input field a unique id:

```
<input id="kilohere_<?= $item_id ?>">
```

Then use that id in your function:

```
<button  type="submit" value = "-" onclick="minusbot(<?= $item_id ?>), submit()"
```

and edit your javascript:

```
function minusbot(id)
    {
        let inputField = document.getElementById('kilohere_' + id)
        inputField.value = parseInt(inputField.value) - 1;
        var checknumifzero = parseInt(inputField.value);

        if(checknumifzero < 1) //preventing to get negative value
        {
            inputField.value = 1;
        }
    }   

    function plusbot(id)
    {
        let inputField = document.getElementById('kilohere_' + id)
        inputField.value = parseInt(inputField.value) + 1;
        var checknumiffifty = parseInt(inputField.value);

        if(checknumiffifty > 50) //just a limit
        {
            inputField.value = 50;
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a variable (`inputField`) to improve readability of your code.

Comment: Not working. The first row does not work  now too.

Comment: What's going wrong? Have you looked at your browser's console? Any errors? And have you changed the plusbot function as well (didn't include it in my answer, I'm not gonna write all your code)?

Comment: <?= $item_id ?> must be ' . $item_id . '

Comment: It worked just for item_id but $key_of_session was the final solution and worked for all.

Comment: I want to show instead of the minus button the delete Button when imput value = 1 so I will edit the question

Comment: I tryed a toggle audıoplayer but dıd not work

Comment: Audioplayer? I saw you tried to edit my answer. Please update your question or comment instead.

Comment: Toggle decrease button to delete button when value = 1,  I mage new question pls have a look